# how to iterate through a list in racket? if the character in the list is alphabetic, I want to add to a new string

Tags: racket

Here is my code? Can anyone tell me how to iterate through a list? if the character in the list is alphabetic, I want to add to a new string

```scm
#lang racket

(define (conversion input)
  (define s (string))
  (let ((char (string->list input)))
    (cond
      [(char-alphabetic? (first (char)))
             (string-append s first)]
      [(char-alphabetic? (rest (char)))
            (string-append s rest)]))
  (display s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic iteration is:

```scm
(define (copy-list lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (car lst)
            (copy-list (cdr lst))))

(copy-list '(1 2 3)) ; ==> (1 2 3)
```

This one actually makes a shallow copy of your list. Sometimes you iterate with keeping some variables to accumulate stuff:

```scm
(define (sum-list lst acc)
  (if (null lst)
      acc
      (sum-list (cdr lst) (+ acc (car lst)))))

(sum-list '(1 2 3)) ; ==> 6
```

Looking at these you'll see a pattern emerges so we have made stuff like `map`, `foldl`, and `foldr` to abstract the iteration:

```scm
(define (copy-list-foldr lst)
  (foldr cons '() lst)

(define (copy-list-map lst)
  (map values lst))

(define (sum-list-foldl lst)
  (foldl + 0 lst))
```

Looking at your challenge I bet you can fix it with a `foldr`.